# Why there is the map is a multiplication by a non-zero integer in case of the complex projective space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Here is the question I am trying to understand the last part of its solution:

Using the cup product structure, show there is no map $\mathbb R P^n \to \mathbb R P^m$ inducing a nontrivial map $H^1(\mathbb R P^m; \mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z ) \to H^1(\mathbb R P^n; \mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z )$ if $n > m.$ What is the corresponding result for maps $\mathbb C P^n \to \mathbb C P^m.$

Here is the solution to this question I found here:[Algebraic Topology Hatcher Chapter 3.2 Problem 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805478/algebraic-topology-hatcher-chapter-3-2-problem-3/3806004#3806004)

**My question is about this solution is:**

Why there the map is a multiplication by a non-zero integer in case of the complex projective space?

Comment: Perhaps you've forgotten to provide the link to the solution you're looking at.

Comment: If you're referring to the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805478/algebraic-topology-hatcher-chapter-3-2-problem-3, what part of the last paragraph is not clear?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez sorry about that I edited my question.

Comment: yes that is the link @JohnPalmieri thank you!

Comment: $H^2(\Bbb CP^n,\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$. What group homomorphisms $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ are there?

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you, got it :)

Comment: Why not leave a comment on that answer asking the author instead of starting a new question?